# wget: only download .listing file

Tags: wget

when a download with wget and user the argument

```
wget url --no-remove-listing
```

I can save the `.listing` file.

but, How I can download only the `.listing` file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--spider` option to prevent wget from downloading anything. The `.listing` file will still be created, of course.

```
wget url --spider --no-remove-listing
```